# Python generating random numbers

Tags: python, python-3.x, random

This is my code:

```
import random
minimum=int(input("Enter minimal value: "))
maximum=int(input("Enter maximum value: "))
howMany = int(input("How many numbers do you want to generate?"))
sum=0
n=1
while n<=howMany:
    num=random.randrange(minimum,maximum)
    num+=sum
    num+=1
    print(num)
print("Python's random average between", minimum, "and", maximum, "is", sum/howMany*100)
```

The problem is that when the user enters the amount of numbers they want generated, it doesnt say anything and python doesnt do anything. It just freezes. What is wrong with my code? Also, how would I calculate the average? I am getting 0.0 as the average.

Comment: `num+=1` should be `n+=1`

Comment: It is much easier to use `for _ in range(howMany):`, then you can't forget to increment

Answer (score 3):

May I recommend using the `for .. in` loop to avoid these types of logical errors?

```
import random
minimum=int(input("Enter minimal value: "))
maximum=int(input("Enter maximum value: "))
howMany = int(input("How many numbers do you want to generate?"))
total=0
for n in range(howMany):
    num=random.randrange(minimum,maximum)
    total+=num
    print(num)
print("Python's random average between", minimum, "and", maximum, "is", total/howMany*100)
```

Indeed, it drives me nuts when I have to use a regular `for` loop in other languages.

Also note that it should be `sum+=num`, not `num+=sum`. `a += b` is the same as `a = a + b` - it's the left-hand-side that gets modified.

Comment: How about `total` instead - so the builtin `sum` isn't shadowed for surprises later on...

Comment: If the OP's using 3, there's no `xrange`.

Answer (score 1):

Increment `n` instead of `num` and `sum` should be incremented by the value of `num`

```
while n<=howMany:
    num=random.randrange(minimum,maximum)
    sum += num 
    n += 1
    print(num)
```

Also to find the average use `sum/howMany` instead of `sum/howMany*100`

Answer (score 1):

I suggest using the built-in `sum` function, on a generator expression, rather than adding up your random values manually. This is a bit more advanced than what you're using, but it's one of the things that Python is really good at:

```
import random

minimum=int(input("Enter minimal value: "))
maximum=int(input("Enter maximum value: "))
howMany = int(input("How many numbers do you want to generate?"))

total = sum(random.randint(minimum, maximum) for _ in range(howMany)) # do the sum

avg = total / howMany # compute the average

# print the output
print("Average of {} random numbers between {} and {} is {:.2}".format(howMany, minimum,
                                                                       maximum, avg))
```

I'm doing a few other things differently too. To start with, I use the name `total` for the sum of the random numbers, so as not to shadow the built in `sum` function. Shadowing an existing name is allowed, but usually a bad idea (it can lead to bugs). Since I'm using the `sum` function, it would be very confusing to use `sum` as a variable name too.

In the generator expression inside the `sum` call, I'm also using `randint` rather than `randrange`, because it includes the maximum value (`randrange` excludes the maximum, like `range` does). I think this better matches the description of "between `minimum` and `maximum`", which suggests (to me at least) the endpoints should be handled symmetrically. If you are using your random numbers for some other purpose, you should be careful that the function you call matches your use, or you can get hard to find bugs.

I also use string formatting to produce the output, rather than passing multiple values to `print`. This allows a lot more flexibility in formatting, if you want it. I use that flexibility to limit the average to two decimal places, rather than Python's default (which is often all the precision available in the floating point number, about 16 decimal places).

Answer (score 0):

If speed is a concern. you could do:

```
import numpy as np
total = np.random.random_integers(minimum, maximum, size=(howMany)).sum()
```

which is roughly 100 times faster than

```
total = sum(random.randint(minimum, maximum) for _ in range(howMany))
```

Answer (score 0):

Here neither `n` nor `howMany` is being updated inside the loop and so the **condition always remains true** giving an infinite loop.

Update either `n` or reduce `howMany` value.